# How to Transcribe R-colored Vowels (ɝ, ɚ, ɑ˞,ɔ˞) in X-SAMPA?

Tags: ipa, vowels, transliteration, sampa

I'm looking at the [Arpabet page on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arpabet), and note some entries like this:

```
Arpabet | IPA | Word Examples
  ER    |  ɝ  | her (HH ER0); bird (B ER1 D); hurt (HH ER1 T), nurse (N ER1 S)
```

Now, I'm trying to convert this Arpabet "ER" into X-SAMPA.  But, I don't see ɝ anywhere in the X-SAMPA specification.  Instead, my reading leads me to see that character ɝ (and some others, like ɚ) are "[R-colored vowels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-colored_vowel)", which *I think* means they can be decomposed into two separate characters instead of written in one digraph character.

My question, in short, is: are these equivalent?

```
ɝ => ɜr
ɚ => ər
ɑ˞ => ɑr
ɔ˞ => ɔr
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't the claim behind the rhotic-hook diacritic. It means that the vowel has the characteristics of the main vowel symbol, but with some kind of r-like raising of the tongue during its production. The sequence [ɑr] means "low back vowel followed by alveolar trill". Apart from the difference in timing (simultaneous vs. sequence) there is a substantial difference in the nature of the r-ishness. If you use the sequences [ɑɹ] etc, they would be more similar (r-coloring is superimposition of "ɹ" quality, not "r"). What might confuse matters is that in English, so-called r-colored vowels are derivable from a sequence of vowel plus consonant *ɹ*.

Comment: Ah ok, I see.  There is no "decomposition", because these are not "composed" of two characters to begin with.  Adding ˞ only modifies the vowel, it does not indicate a second character.  And as you mention some languages may not distinguish (as in English, ɝ and ɜɹ would be allophones).


BTW, the X-SAMPA page does mention how to make these ligatures: it's the backtick (\`), as in "3\`" or "@\`".  I just didn't look hard enough : )